# How to extract data from a PCM file into a buffer [Swift]

Tags: swift, networking, audio, pcm

I have a project where I'm sending and receiving data over apple's NWConnection listener, and my goal is to be able to send raw PCM data from a local file to the receiver end where I will then place the data in the buffer and play it. Focusing on just the first part, I can't seem to find how I can extract the data from a local PCM file to send over to the receiver using Swift.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the format of your "local file"? What have you tried so far? If the file is PCM, then simply sending the contents would already be "raw PCM" it seems.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner The file is PCM, but I'm just unsure how to extract the data from the file into a container in swift. I've tried doing it how I normally read from a file like so
`let data = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)` but of course that's for text files so it I just get random data that I can't use.

Comment: I'm not a Swift guy, unfortunately. If the PCM is numeric, perhaps you can read the data as a series of bytes and assemble the bytes into the PCM values? For example, if the PCM is 16-bit, you would append two bytes to get a single value. The order of the bytes would have to be known though. 16-bit values can be either big-endian or little-endian. Am just guessing here.